# Alert Dialog not working as expected in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I was trying to show 2 dialog same time and when i open second dialog, its not focusing on the widget that was in second dialog, its focusing on the widget thats on first dialog that i have opened before.

Is this issue or am i not supposed to open 2 dialog at same time?

Here is video to the issue

[image]

Here is first dialog code

```
showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (_) => 
AlertDialog(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 16,
                    height: 32,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppColors.colorFFBC99,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 16,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    S.addaRecipe,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall!.copyWith(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      S.recipeBy,
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .labelLarge!
                          .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: CustomMyDropDownButton(label: 'dsfsdsf'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          content: Form(
            // key: formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          S.addPhotos,
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .labelLarge!
                              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 8,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          // height: 200,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Wrap(
                            children: [
                              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    width: 200,
                                    height: 200,
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        S.recipeNetworkImage,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                    ),
                                    width: 200,
                                    height: 200,
                                    child: const Center(
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.add,
                                        size: 32,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        CustomTextField(
                          showLabel: true,
                          // controller: textEditingController,
                          label: S.recipeName,
                          validator: (v) {
                            if (v!.isEmpty) {
                              return 'This field is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        CustomTextField(
                          showLabel: true,
                          // controller: textEditingController,
                          label: S.description,
                          validator: (v) {
                            if (v!.isEmpty) {
                              return 'This field is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 32,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              S.nutritionalInfo,
                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .labelLarge!
                                  .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                                    title: const Text(
                                      S.addNutrition,
                                    ),
                                    content: Column(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      children: const [
                                        CustomTextField(
                                          showLabel: true,
                                          label: S.name,
                                        ),
                                        CustomTextField(
                                          showLabel: true,
                                          label: S.value,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    actions: [
                                      CustomOutlinedButton(
                                          name: S.close,
                                          onPress: () {
                                            context.pop();
                                          }),
                                      CustomElevatedButton(
                                        name: S.add,
                                        onPress: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 8,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                          child: 1 == 1
                              ? Text(
                                  "Nutrition Info....",
                                )
                              : Column(
                                  children: [
                                    for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
                                      ListTile(
                                        leading:
                                            Icon(Icons.horizontal_split_rounded),
                                        title: Text('Calories'),
                                        subtitle: Text('237'),
                                        trailing: IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {},
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 32,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          S.steps,
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .labelLarge!
                              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 8,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: AppColors.colorF4F4F4,
                          height: 300,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
                          child: HtmlEditor(
                            controller: HtmlEditorController(),
                            htmlEditorOptions: const HtmlEditorOptions(
                              hint: "Steps....",
                            ),
                            otherOptions: const OtherOptions(
                                height: 400,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 32,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 32,
                ),
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '',
                      maxLines: 3,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '',
                      maxLines: 3,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            CustomOutlinedButton(
                name: S.close,
                onPress: () {
                  context.pop();
                }),
            CustomElevatedButton(
              name: S.add,
              onPress: () {},
            ),
          ],
        );
```

Here is the code of second dialog show dialog

```
 showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text(
                              S.addNutrition,
                            ),
                            content: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: const [
                                CustomTextField(
                                  showLabel: true,
                                  label: S.name,
                                ),
                                CustomTextField(
                                  showLabel: true,
                                  label: S.value,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            actions: [
                              CustomOutlinedButton(
                                  name: S.close,
                                  onPress: () {
                                    context.pop();
                                  }),
                              CustomElevatedButton(
                                name: S.add,
                                onPress: () {},
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
```

Here is customtextfield code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? label;
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;
  final Function(String?)? onSaved;
  final bool showLabel;
  final bool enableSuggestions;
  final bool autocorrect;
  final TextInputType? keyBoardType;
  final Function(String)? onChange;
  final bool showSuffixIcon;

  const CustomTextField({
    Key? key,
    this.label,
    this.controller,
    this.validator,
    this.onSaved,
    this.enableSuggestions = true,
    this.autocorrect = true,
    this.keyBoardType,
    this.onChange,
    this.showSuffixIcon = false,
    this.showLabel = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomTextField> createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  final textFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();

  bool _obscured = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    if (widget.showSuffixIcon) {
      _obscured = true;
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  void _toggleObscured() {
    setState(() {
      _obscured = !_obscured;
      if (textFieldFocusNode.hasPrimaryFocus)
        return; // If focus is on text field, dont unfocus
      textFieldFocusNode.canRequestFocus =
          false; // Prevents focus if tap on eye
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        widget.showLabel
            ? Text(
                widget.label!,
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .labelLarge!
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              )
            : const SizedBox(),
        SizedBox(
          height: widget.showLabel ? 8 : 0,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: widget.controller,
          validator: widget.validator,
          onSaved: widget.onSaved,
          onChanged: widget.onChange,
          focusNode: textFieldFocusNode,
          obscureText: _obscured,
          enableSuggestions: widget.enableSuggestions,
          autocorrect: widget.autocorrect,
          keyboardType: widget.keyBoardType,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(8),
              ),
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black12,
              ),
            ),
            focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(8),
              ),
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black12,
              ),
            ),
            errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(8),
              ),
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            border: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(8),
              ),
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black12,
              ),
            ),
            labelText: widget.showLabel ? null : widget.label,
            // labelStyle: CustomTextStyle.kTextStyle16400.copyWith(
            //   color: AppColors.textColor2,
            // ),
            suffixIcon: widget.showSuffixIcon
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 4, 0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: _toggleObscured,
                      child: Icon(
                        _obscured
                            ? Icons.visibility_rounded
                            : Icons.visibility_off_rounded,
                        size: 24,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : null,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include `CustomTextField`?

Comment: ok, i will add it

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `autofocus: true,` on your  `CustomTextField`. It should do handle rest I believe.

```dart
TextField(
  autofocus: true,
);
```

Comment: i have updated the video, please see the issue again

Comment: does `autofocus` work? if fails, can you provide minimal full snippet, coz `CustomTextField` is hidden there. try to provide from 1st showDialog

Comment: yes i have added autofocus: true, still same issue.Its not only textfield, i am not able to click on any action buttons either

Comment: the second dialog was on top of HtmlEditor which was in first dialog

Comment: doe it work after removing  `HtmlEditor`?

Comment: yes, it works as expected after removing it.

Comment: sorry cant say about `HtmlEditor`